# Decode Base64 in Python that was encoded in Perl

Tags: python, perl, encoding, base64

I have base64 encoded data that was created with Perl, using `MIME::Base64` with `encode_base64($data)`.

The result is: `ahX/OxLY/BBR4Wy+n+a3Mg==`

When I decode this in Perl, I get `j?;??Q?l???2`. If I write that out to a file, it looks like this: `jˇ;ÿ¸Q·læüÊ∑2`

However, when I try to use the same base64 encoded data and decode with python `base64.b64decode(data), I get:`
b'j\x15\xff;\x12\xd8\xfc\x10Q\xe1l\xbe\x9f\xe6\xb72'`

If I decoded it to `latin1`, the result is a bit closer: `'j\x15ÿ;\x12Øü\x10Qál¾\x9fæ·2'`, but I need the exact same data.

How can I get the exact same output from python? What am I missing?

(The Perl `$data` itself was supposedly generated with urandom `read(DEV,$data,16);`.

Comment: This is probably the same data (in different representations). Write the bytes out to a file (in binary mode, not text) and compare the files.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the same string in both Perl and Python.

```
$ perl -e'
   use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
   my $raw = "\x6A\x15\xFF\x3B\x12\xD8\xFC\x10\x51\xE1\x6C\xBE\x9F\xE6\xB7\x32";
   CORE::say encode_base64($raw, "");
'
ahX/OxLY/BBR4Wy+n+a3Mg==

$ python3 <<__END_OF_PROG__
import base64
encoded = "ahX/OxLY/BBR4Wy+n+a3Mg==";
expected = b"\x6A\x15\xFF\x3B\x12\xD8\xFC\x10\x51\xE1\x6C\xBE\x9F\xE6\xB7\x32";
raw = base64.b64decode(encoded)
print(raw == expected)
__END_OF_PROG__
True
```

That's because `base64.b64decode(data)` didn't produce

```
b'j\x15\xff;\x12\xd8\xfc\x10Q\xe1l\xbe\x9f\xe6\xb72'
```

What it produced was the string produced by that Python string literal, the string consisting of the following 16 bytes (hex):

```
6A 15 FF 3B 12 D8 FC 10 51 E1 6C BE 9F E6 B7 32
```

That is the very string you had in Perl to produce `ahX/OxLY/BBR4Wy+n+a3Mg==`.